# Clean Architecture - Use external library

Tags: clean-architecture

I want to understand how to use clean architecture the proper way. For example, if you wanted to create a generic repository, I would typically put the interface in a library project, since the definition of it will not change. If developing multiple projects, lets say a shipment api and a products api, I would want to use the same generic repository interface for both application. Is that something you can do in clean architecture?

Comment: Have you found a decision? I'm facing the same problem with **external libraries** in use  now _(not for DB/storage access)_ and don't know which artifact and layer to use

Answer (score 0):

Clean Architecture is a big story. To get a more clear idea about it I recommend that you read the book of his owner Robert Martin or take a quick look to his post on his official blog.

But if I focused o your question: Frameworks, external Api, databases... in clean architecture are dependencies. They represent details. Your code, I mean the code that resolve your business domain should not be disturbed by these kind of details.
How this is resolved in real world, by dependency injection, revert of control and Port/Adapter pattern...

In your case you have 2 different requirements.

- The first one, and the obvious one, is your need to use Repository pattern to handle your database read/write operation. These a detail/infrastructure level. What your domain should see is just Interfaces of your repositories that expose these operations.
- The second one, it seems that you have a more deeper requirement, you want to create a generic repository, and this is really the details of implementation of your repository (a detail of a detail :) ). That is why clean architecture focus on separating this kind of things.

So if you do things with a clean way, you will notice that changing on the way that you implement your repository will never disturb your domain.

I think also you mentioned that you want to add a common generic repository between 2 applications. Try to check if this code is really so important to be separated as Internal Framework. May be it concerns a simple class ? Just code it twice in your 2 applications. Sometimes duplication is good.
Check please about good and bad duplication.

If really you need some code to be an Internal Framework and you thing that reusing it is so important, handle it in your code like any external Framework. Add an adapter layer to make your domain code less dependent on it (more precisely less dependent on its change).

I hope I was clear.
Thanks.